# Find the most freq sequence amongst other sequences

Tags: python, numpy, bioinformatics, dna-sequence

I was given 10 DNA sequences each one consisting of 18 bases and I was asked to write a program that calculates the most frequent sequence(consensus) amongst all these sequences. For example let's say I have "ACTGGA","ACCAAT","CTTAGG", "ATGAAG"

The consensus sequence would be "A(CT)TA(GA)G" because in the first base position of each sequence "A" exists 3/4 times.For the second base position of each sequence i have 2 sequences with "C" and 2 sequences with "T" . So far my consensus sequence looks like A(CT), because i have established that "A" occurs 75% of the time in position 1 while for position 2 there's a 50-50% chance "T" or "C" will appear etc.So, i will include both "C" and "T" in the second position of my Consensus. Now I am trying to do this in python using pycharm even though I am not very familiar with it. I just wanted to push myself into learning something new. My problem is that when I am reading the txt file into a numpy array like this:

```
seq_array = np.asarray(list(map(str.strip, seq)))
```

My array ends up being 1d like (10,) instead of (10,18) so I can't iterate through every row and col in order to count each char. So how do I read the file into a 2d size (10,18)? and instead of iterating every `seq_array[r][c]`, is there a faster way I can get to the most frequent sequence?

Comment: What is `seq`? A list of strings?

Comment: What do you want to happen on a conflict? (2 or more bases appear the same number of times in a position)

Comment: seq refers to `with open("DNAsequences.txt","r") as seq:` . The only conflict i can think of is having 2 out of 4 bases in the same position for 5 and 5 sequences respectively e.g first 5 sequences in position 1/18 start with A and the other 5 in position 1/18 start with C. In this case i want both sequnces as possible frequent ones.

Comment: It's unclear what the "frequency" of a sequence is since one is composed of bases that each have their own frequencies. Could you define what you mean by the former better? Some sample data  and code that determined the value would also be very helpful…

Comment: I'd happily provide some code but the problem is I don't have any yet since I'm stuck at the very beginning. Forgive me for not using the appropriate terminology before but i have now updated the original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you are having with generating your multidimensional array:

```
list(map(str.strip, seq))  # Returns a list of strings

list(map(list, map(str.strip, seq)))  # Will return a list of lists

seq_array = np.asarray(list(map(list, map(str.strip, seq))))
```